# Transparent text which ignores the first background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know if this is possible in css, I am sure that it can be done in js but i don't know how...

I have a div with a background and a text that is in another div with another background.  What I would like is the text to be transparent and have the first-background as the text background.  I don't know if this is clear so I've created a fiddle for this:

```
<div id="first-background">
    <div id="second-background">
        <h1>This text should be transparent and have the first-background as its background and ignore the second background.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K2Ytv/

Comment: It's doing exactly what you wanted already...? Or maybe I'm not getting it right.

Comment: im also not sure what you mean? you want to switch the background of first div to sec. div with jQuery?

Comment: the text should be transparent and ignore the #second-background. it should have the #first-background...

Comment: then just dont set the background in sec. div..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This technique is called clipping mask.

You can refer to **[DEMOS AND TUTORIALS ON CLIPPING MASK](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-masking/)** to achieve what you want.

Comment: wow, is this what he ask for? carzy, never would thout taht...:)

Comment: Yes, I think this is it... However this is css3, so it won't work with a lot of browser :'( (+1 though)

Comment: Yes @BalintBako It is a CSS3 Technique. Webkit browsers have a support for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this thing out.

```
 #first-background{
        background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_1zl6-e5P_loFXt6vq6aA50usSJwm2amdkqPaVSQums5KalLX4A);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
    }

    #second-background{
        background-color: red;
        opacity: 0.5;
        width: 700px;
        height: 435px;
    }
    h3{
        color: rgba(53,90,150,0.4);

    }
```